# Basic gRPC version not working

Tags: python, grpc

I was trying to implement a simple gRPC server/client and have narrowed down the problem to even basic gRPC Python implementations not working on my machine.

Here is what I tried:

```
pip install grpcio grpcio-tools
git clone https://github.com/grpc/grpc.git
cd grpc/examples/python/route_guide
python run_codegen.py # Everything breaks whether I include this step or not
python route_guide_server.py
```

And getting the following error:

```
-------------- GetFeature --------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "route_guide_client.py", line 119, in <module>
    run()
  File "route_guide_client.py", line 109, in run
    guide_get_feature(stub)
  File "route_guide_client.py", line 48, in guide_get_feature
    latitude=409146138, longitude=-746188906))
  File "route_guide_client.py", line 34, in guide_get_one_feature
    feature = stub.GetFeature(point)
  File "/Users/p/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 514, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/Users/p/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 448, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED
    details = "Method not found!"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1530451116.454542000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1083,"grpc_message":"Method not found!","grpc_status":12}"
>
```

More [detail](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/15920) on my machine config if useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Realised that the port `50051` was occupied!

Comment: This helped me in a roundabout way. I was running into "Method not found!" and "Method not implemented!" even though I'm staring at the code where I just wrote it. 

Turns out I have 4 copies of my server process still running, on the same port. A test script had spawned them in the background `&` and I forgot to kill them. Why didn't this throw "port in use"? who knows!